# Relatively open subset

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

From  Complex Analysis by Ahlfors, pg 54,

... If we regard the closed interval $0\leqslant x\leqslant1$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R$ then the semi closed interval $0\leqslant x<1$ is relatively open but not open in $\mathbb R$.

> How is it not open in $\mathbb R$?

I am finding it difficult to understand the concept of relatively open sets a simple example would help.

Answer (score 1):

The set $[0,1)$ is not open in $\mathbb R$ because $0\in[0,1)$ but there is no $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\subset[0,1)$.

However, it *is* relatively open in $[0,1]$, since $[0,1)=(-1,1)\cap[0,1]$ and $(-1,1)$ *is* an open subset of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Alternatively, the open ball of radius $1$ around $0$ relatiev to $[0,1]$ is all points of $[0,1]$ with distance $<1$ to $0$, i.e. $[0,1)$ which is thus open in $[0,1]$, as an open ball.